# Smarty mysql date + 1 day

Tags: mysql, date, smarty

I have a variable that give me the date from mysql:

```
{row.date}
```

How can i add now 1 day to this?

Exampe:
row.date = 2015-07-23
and i wish = 2015-07-24

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date functions to do this. Here is the way to achieve this:

```
date_add('2015-07-23', Interval 1 Day);
```

You can replace **"2015-07-23"** to column name which contains date in your select query.

Comment: But how i can to this in the template part?

Comment: Why you want to do this in template,If you can easily do this in SQL query.

Comment: because i need the query for the real result. the +1 day i need for another part of the displaying in template.

Comment: But better way to do this is just select two columns with real result and +1 day.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql itself you can get like this
I would prefer this rather doing in php

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM table;
```

or

```
$startDate = $row['date']; // 2015-07-23
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$startDate +1 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this done in your Smarty template, then you can archive it this way:

```
{"$row.date +1 Days"|date_format:'Y-m-d'}
```

However, I would usually advise against doing too much math and other logic in a Smarty template. In most use cases, it would be better to do the math somewhere within your (php) application and then display the result within the template.